# PHP - regex match a URL that contains parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following pattern to match URLs in a string:

```
$pattern = '%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s';
```

This works pretty well. However, the match fails with URLs like this:

```
https://twitter.com/search/from:username(exclude:replies)min_faves:20
```

It seems to stop at the parentheses. Any ideas on how I could modify the pattern to match this type of URL? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're matching URLs in a general string, you generally can't match all possible URLs. You have to decide what characters end the URL, and they can't be allowed in the URL.

Comment: For instance if someone could write `(my URL is http://example.com/abc)` you can't allow `)` in the URL.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: You can write `[\w\d]+` as `\w+` as `\w` by itself also matches a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Take the parentheses of of your negated character class and it works.

```
[^\s<>]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/4amF6u/1/

Full version:

```
$pattern = '%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s';
```